# continue when delimiter is not present and write contents anyway

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of mp3 files that I want to print in: artist, title the following works but, if it encounters a file that doesn't have the delimter of " - " it stops ofcourse, how can I make it continue and just print in artist whats in the filename?

```
for mp3file in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive = True):

        path, filename = os.path.split(mp3file)
        NoExtension = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

        print('Name: '+NoExtension)
        splitFilename = NoExtension.split(' - ', 1)
        print('Artist: '+splitFilename[0]+'\n')
        print('Title: '+splitFilename[1])
```

OUTPUT

```
Name: CamelPhat - Both [Club Remix] [Clean, Music-In, Music-Out, Mashup Redrum]
Artist: CamelPhat
Title: Both [Club Remix] [Clean, Music-In, Music-Out, Mashup Redrum]

Name: Bob Marley - Is This Love (Montmartre - Remix) [Peak Hour Redrum] [Mashup] [Clean, Beat-In, Beat-Out, Mashup]
Artist: Bob Marley
Title: Is This Love (Montmartre - Remix) [Peak Hour Redrum] [Mashup] [Clean, Beat-In, Beat-Out, Mashup]

Name: Molly (Dj Nasa Secret Bootleg)
Artist: Molly (Dj Nasa Secret Bootleg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Scripts\IDremoveAndReplace.py", line 20, in <module>
    print('Title: '+splitFilename[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your code in a try - except block and have the exception print what you want

For example

```
for mp3file in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive = True):
    try:
        path, filename = os.path.split(mp3file)
        NoExtension = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

        print('Name: '+NoExtension)
        splitFilename = NoExtension.split(' - ', 1)
        print('Artist: '+splitFilename[0]+'\n')
        print('Title: '+splitFilename[1])
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
        #Some other logic here
        print('Cannot find title')
```

Comment: The life of a python noob 8 lines of code after 1 hour of google, answer in 1 min on stack :) this works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a try-block:

```
for mp3file in glob.glob("**/*.mp3", recursive = True):

        path, filename = os.path.split(mp3file)
        NoExtension = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]

        print('Name: ' + NoExtension)

        splitFilename = NoExtension.split(' - ', 1)
        print('Artist: ' + splitFilename[0] + '\n')

        try:                 
            print('Title: ' + splitFilename[1])
        except IndexError as ie:
            print('Title: ' + splitFilename[0])
```